# Module for enforcing mandatory minimum number of tags in content type field?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

The built-in tag field functionality allows definition of a *maximum* number of tags, but not a minimum number.

Is there a contrib module to enforce a minimum?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [Field Validation](https://drupal.org/project/field_validation).

> This module adds an extra tab to each field instance, allowing you to
>   specify validation rules for your field instances.

Just create your term/entity reference field and set up a validation rule using the *Number of Selections* rule.

Leave the maximum number of fields empty, and enter the minimum you require as the minimum required values.